# Laravel own package can't find service provider

Tags: laravel, package

I’m new to Laravel package development, I’m started developing my first package like described here: 
http://www.websanova.com/blog/laravel/creating-a-new-package-in-laravel-5-part-1-package-workflow

When the package resides in the package folder of my test environment all things work fine. But when I require the package via Composer from github the service provider is not found. I try fix it for hours and hours and have no clue how to leverage. I uploaded the package on github https://github.com/tok3/publisher.

In my `composer.json` I added the repository to bypass Packagist:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "tok3/laravel42-firebird-support",
                "version": "1.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/tok3/laravel42-firebird-support/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/tok3/laravel42-firebird-support.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "dev-master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

After that it's possible to load the package like every other package by adding the line below to the require section of my `composer.json`:

```
"tok3/publisher": "@beta"
```

Then I run `composer update` and the package gets loaded and stored in the `vendor` folder. After that I fill in the provider and facade in `config/app.php`.

```
Tok3\Publisher\PublisherServiceProvider::class,

'Publisher' => Tok3\Publisher\PublisherFacade::class,
```

Now I run `composer dump-autoload` without any errors but when I run `php artisan serve` I get this message:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Class 'Tok3\Publisher\PublisherServiceProvider' not found

No glue what happened here, I can’t figure out any difference to other packages. I am using PhpStorm-IDE and when I click on the `PublisherServiceProvider::class`  in `config/app.php` the class is found.

I’ve chased the web for hours and did not found any appropriate solution. Hope someone could help me or give hint to solve.

Comment: In your code you are requesting a repository called firebird-support. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry copy and pasted from my incorrect README.md from github.
````

Comment: But in my code I'm referencing the right package: "publisher". 
README.md is fixed: https://github.com/tok3/publisher.
Maybe someone with editor rights is so kind and will fix my post, sorry !